# Broswers on Mac are adding /%20 to url when I use fetch api to do a POST or GET request, NEXT JS 13.5+

Tags: node.js, macos, url, next.js, fetch-api

```
 const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/example`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(data.Email),
        }
      );
```

NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000

So I created my own endpoints with how Next Js allows to do it. Now this works perfectly when I run the custom server or dev in all Windows PCs, and even on my iPhone. I use my localIp to then use safari to search for the site so I can see it in my iPhone.

Everything works, I can even log in and the data is fetched according to the user logged in (session token).

But I wanted to test safari on Mac, and if I run the server or dev on a Mac OS the fetch fails.

It fails on all browsers on this mac. (tested Chrome and Opera)

It has the same node version, repo branch up to date, same .env (gotta check if there is white space in the .env place, this was copy pasted since I don't track the .env in git)

But the problem I noticed is that the url that the browser is using, it adds spaces or seems like it because it adds gibberish and %20. So it looks like http://localhost:3000/%20%24DAH/api/example

(might need to check what exactly comes after the %20 but yeah)

I did a console.log and there are not spaces for the url I'm giving it so I don't understand.

I made sure that in the middleware, http://localhost:3000 is in the allow origins as well.

This used to work before but now it doesn't.

My thought is that in the .env file there is space or whitespace after the value of the enviromental variable.

I also tested with hard coded url and still nothing so that might exclude the whitespace thing.

This might not be a problem since Im going to host this in a VPC or VPS because I use a custom server because I did my own CronJobs and something else. I didn't use those services to run crons on a serverless app.

Any thoughts?